# SQL view to display records even no matching in many to many relation

Tags: sql, sql-server, many-to-many

I have 3 tables:

```
Role         
------
[Id],
[Name]


Scope
------
[Id],
[Name]


RoleScope
------
[RoleId],
[ScopeId],
[View],
[Add],
[Edit],
[Delete],
```

This is the relation many to many.

I have also the view which shows me that relation

```
CREATE VIEW View_RolesWithScopes
AS
SELECT
    [Role].Id AS RoleId,
    [Role].[Name] AS RoleName,
    [RoleScope].ScopeId,
    [Scope].[Name] AS ScopeName,
    [RoleScope].[View],
    [RoleScope].[Add],
    [RoleScope].[Edit],
    [RoleScope].[Delete]
FROM 
    dbo.[Role] [Role]
    LEFT JOIN dbo.RoleScope [RoleScope] ON [RoleScope].RoleId = [Role].Id 
    LEFT JOIN dbo.Scope [Scope] ON [Scope].Id = [RoleScope].ScopeId
```

How to update this view to display record even there is no relation between in RoleScope

---

Example:

```
Role
------
Id | Name
1  | Role1
2  | Role2


Scope
------
Id | Name
1  | Scope1
2  | Scope2
3  | Scope3


RoleScope
------
RoleId | ScopeId | View | Add | Edit | Delete
1      | 1       | 1    | 1   | 1    | 0
1      | 2       | 1    | 0   | 1    | 0
```

Current result:

```
View_RolesWithScopes
------
RoleId | ScopeId | View | Add | Edit | Delete
1      | 1       | 1    | 1   | 1    | 0
1      | 2       | 1    | 0   | 1    | 0
2      | NULL    | NULL | NULL| NULL | NULL
```

Expected result:

```
View_RolesWithScopes
------
RoleId | ScopeId | View | Add | Edit | Delete
1      | 1       | 1    | 1   | 1    | 0
1      | 2       | 1    | 0   | 1    | 0
1      | 3       | 0    | 0   | 0    | 0
2      | 1       | 0    | 0   | 0    | 0
2      | 2       | 0    | 0   | 0    | 0
2      | 3       | 0    | 0   | 0    | 0
```

Comment: Since you do LEFT JOIN, you will get the new role.

Comment: @jarlh I've updated description, with another case.

Comment: Try FULL OUTER JOIN, if you also want a scope with no role.

Comment: @jarlh Check my fresh example now, you think that FULL OUTER JOIN will help me here?

Comment: Yes, but you will get NULL for missing relations. Do `COALESCE(column, 0)` to get 0 instead of NULL.

Comment: @jarlh I'm keep trying but, can't figure out how to make it work, would you be so kind to help me more, please?

Comment: Simply start with FULL OUTER JOIN instead of LEFT JOIN. Does the return result make sense?

Comment: @jarlh I replaced both LEFT JOIN with FULL OUTER JOIN and it returns 5 records, but RoleId and ScopeId are NULL

Comment: Great. Now use `COALESCE(column, 0)` to get 0 instead of NULL.

Comment: @jarlh `COALESCE(column, 0)` makse sense for View/Add/Edit/Delete column, but what about the RoleId and ScopeId.

Comment: Use COALESCE everywhere! (Any column can be NULL when you do FULL OUTER JOIN.)

Comment: @jarlh but I don't want to have NULL or 0 under the RoleId/ScopeId. Check my example in post above.

Comment: "_Assuming that I'll add new role, without updating RoleScope table_" means ScopeId will be NULL, or 0 if you do COALESCE.

Comment: A [mcve] and/or fiddle (https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019) would make things clearer.

Comment: @jarlh Regarding to "Assuming that I'll add new role, without updating RoleScope table" - I meant this is how it works now, but I expect the result as it is in the table at the bottom of the post

Comment: That's why a [mcve] is a great way to show what you really want.

Comment: Please add some sample data to your question, specific all the data that lead to your expected result

Comment: I've added example

Comment: @jarlh did you see my update? Is it enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make all of the values appear you could use CROSS JOIN between the ROLES table and the SCOPES table followed by LEFT JOIN to ROLESCOPES.  To have the appropriate columns from ROLESCOPES zero'ed out you could use ISNULL.

```
drop table if exists #roles;
go
create table #roles (
  r_id              int primary key not null, 
  [name]            varchar(10) not null);

insert #roles(r_id, [name]) values
(1, 'Role1'),
(2, 'Role2');

drop table if exists #scopes;
go
create table #scopes (
  s_id              int primary key not null, 
  [name]            varchar(10) not null);

insert #scopes(s_id, [name]) values
(1, 'Scope1'),
(2, 'Scope2'),
(3, 'Scope3');

drop table if exists #rolescopes;
go
create table #rolescopes (
  r_id              int not null, 
  s_id              int not null, 
  [View]            int not null,
  [Add]             int not null,
  [Edit]            int not null,
  [Delete]          int not null);

insert #rolescopes(r_id, s_id, [View], [Add], [Edit], [Delete]) values
(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0),
(1, 2, 1, 0, 1, 0);

select r.r_id, s.s_id,
       isnull(rs.[View],0) [View],
       isnull(rs.[Add],0) [Add],
       isnull(rs.[Edit],0) [Edit],
       isnull(rs.[Delete],0) [Delete]
from #roles r
     cross join #scopes s
     left join #rolescopes rs on r.r_id=rs.r_id
                                 and s.s_id=rs.s_id;
```

```
r_id    s_id    View    Add Edit    Delete
1       1       1       1   1       0
1       2       1       0   1       0
1       3       0       0   0       0
2       1       0       0   0       0
2       2       0       0   0       0
2       3       0       0   0       0
```

Comment: But `ScopeId` is missing

Comment: It's just renamed as s_id.  RoleId is renamed as r_id

Comment: I meant - it will be `NULL`

Comment: My bad, I had typo

Comment: @DiPix the r_id (RoleId) column and s_id (ScopeId) column are specified as NOT NULL in the base tables.  The CROSS JOIN guarantees the RoleId and ScopeId will not be NULL in the query

Answer (score 1):

Use `Subquery` and `cross join` to get Cartesian join of roleid and scopeid,`Full Join` to prodcue null values and `IIF` to distinguishing null values as follows

```
SELECT RS.roleid,
       RS.scopeid,
       IIF(RSS.[view] IS NULL, 0, RSS.[view])     [View],
       IIF(RSS.[add] IS NULL, 0, RSS.[add])       [Add],
       IIF(RSS.[edit] IS NULL, 0, RSS.[edit])     [Edit],
       IIF(RSS.[delete] IS NULL, 0, RSS.[delete]) [Delete]
FROM   (SELECT r.id AS RoleId,
               s.id AS ScopeId
        FROM   roles r
               CROSS JOIN scopes s) RS
       FULL JOIN rolescopes RSS
              ON RS.roleid = RSS.roleid
                 AND RS.scopeid = RSS.scopeid
```

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=d9190b3b5cf4f0183c77a32fd96b2ba5)

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to fill in the missing rows like this:

```sql
SELECT * FROM RoleScope
UNION SELECT
  Role.Id, Scope.Id, 0, 0, 0, 0
FROM Role CROSS JOIN Scope
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 FROM RoleScope
  WHERE Role.id=RoleScope.RoleId AND
        Scope.id=RoleScope.ScopeId);
```

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=0b65edcbab31631f8b877fad27df1c2d)

Answer (score 0):

My query is not exactly same.

```
drop table if exists #roles;
go
create table #roles (
  RoleId              int primary key not null, 
  [name]            varchar(10) not null);

insert #roles(RoleId, [name]) values
(1, 'Role1'),
(2, 'Role2');
drop table if exists #scopes;
go
create table #scopes (
  ScopeId              int primary key not null, 
  [name]            varchar(10) not null);

insert #scopes(ScopeId, [name]) values
(1, 'Scope1'),
(2, 'Scope2'),
(3, 'Scope3');

drop table if exists #rolescopes;
go
create table #rolescopes (
roleScopeId              int identity(1,1) primary key not null, 
  RoleId              int not null, 
  ScopeId              int not null, 
  [View]            int not null,
  [Add]             int not null,
  [Edit]            int not null,
  [Delete]          int not null);

create nonclustered index ix_RID_SID on #rolescopes(RoleId,ScopeId) include([View],[Add],[Edit],[Delete]  )

insert #rolescopes(RoleId, ScopeId, [View], [Add], [Edit], [Delete]) values
(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0),
(1, 2, 1, 0, 1, 0);





    SELECT
    [Role].RoleId AS RoleId,
    [Role].[Name] AS RoleName,
    [Scope].ScopeId,
    [Scope].[Name] AS ScopeName
   into #temp 
FROM 
    #scopes [Scope] 
     join
     #roles [Role] on 1=1

     select t.* ,
     isnull([RoleScope].[View],0) [View],
    isnull([RoleScope].[Add],0) [Add],
    isnull([RoleScope].[Edit],0) [Edit],
    isnull([RoleScope].[Delete],0) [Delete]
     from  #temp t
     LEFT JOIN #rolescopes [RoleScope] ON t.ScopeId = [RoleScope].ScopeId 

     drop table #temp
```

1. Created index on table rolescope.
2. I put result of `cross join` between `role` and `Scope` into `temp` table then join the `temp` table and `rolescope`,thinking that `performance` will be good if there are milion of records.
3. I forgot to change dataType from `INT` to `TinyINT` .It matter if there are millions of records.